# Receive notification in chat with fcm

Tags: android

Hi there I'm building the chat app using firebase and I would like to push notification when a user send message to another user with FCM. 
Any help please

Comment: read this https://blog.chizobaogbonna.me/device-to-device-push-notification-using-cloud-functions-for-firebase-5e607d74d7a2

Answer (score 0):

add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'` to your `app/build.gradle` file.
and below code to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service
   android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
   android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

   private static final String TAG = "MyFMService";

   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       // Handle data payload of FCM messages.
       Log.d(TAG, "FCM Message Id: " + remoteMessage.getMessageId());
       Log.d(TAG, "FCM Notification Message: " +
               remoteMessage.getNotification());
       Log.d(TAG, "FCM Data Message: " + remoteMessage.getData());
   }
}
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIdService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

   private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
   private static final String FRIENDLY_ENGAGE_TOPIC = "friendly_engage";

   /**
    * The Application's current Instance ID token is no longer valid 
    * and thus a new one must be requested.
    */
   @Override
   public void onTokenRefresh() {
       // If you need to handle the generation of a token, initially or
       // after a refresh this is where you should do that.
       String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
       Log.d(TAG, "FCM Token: " + token);

       // Once a token is generated, we subscribe to topic.
       FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()
               .subscribeToTopic(FRIENDLY_ENGAGE_TOPIC);
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you